# Running 21k with a slightly bad knee (ligament damage) - knee sleeve/brace recommendation

Tags: running, knees, knee-pain, half-marathon

**Background**

25 year old male with a small tear to my MCL on my right knee (at 21 years old). I've done a couple of half marathons since then. I wear a knee sleeve which compresses it and it does help a little. I'm also flat footed but wear an appropriate flat foot shoe.

**Problem**

I'll admit my fitness isn't up to half marathon standards yet however I've noticed a recurring theme during my long distance runs. For all my 21k runs, a small twinge in my knee will start at around 11 - 13km and with that fear, I will always stop running because I know it's my knee telling me it's not doing so well. I'm not exactly dead tired at this point either and it's frustrating because I know fitness-wise, I can do better if not limited by the knee.

**Questions**

So my first question, are there any more supportive knee sleeves/braces for MCL weakness?
Second and much more open ended, any advise in general for my situation?

Comment: The longer you run, the more tired you'll get, which results in sloppier form. This could be your issue on longer runs. Are you working with a physical therapist? They could teach you some exercises to strengthen the muscles that support your knee to keep this from happening.

Comment: As someone who’s just been benched for the next 12 weeks because of some ACL injuries and a baker’s cyst on each knee, please be smart and consult a specialist before asking random people on the internet.